# change of variable in partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have nonlinear Schrodinger equation of the form, 
$\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}+b_1\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+(\frac{ib_2}{2})\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2}=i\gamma|A|^2A$, 
where $b_1$, $b_2$ and $\gamma$ are constants.  I need to transform this equation into the form
$\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}+(\frac{ib_2}{2})\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial T^2}=i\gamma|A|^2A$,
using the transformation $T=t-zb_1$.  Can anyone explain how could I transform using change of variables theory?